# iOS 10 NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray not working as before

Tags: swift3, ios10

It seems with the release of iOS 10, a few things have broken. The major one for me has been the use of NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray. Both no longer seem to be able to parse a string of JSON and instead give out a nil while in pre iOS 10 they populated as expected. The only way around this I've found is to use NSDictionary and NSArray respectively and then use the init methods to cast back. For example:

```
let json = "{ \"code\": \"abcde\", \"name\": \"JP Morgan\" }"
json as! NSMutableDictionary // gives nil
NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: json as! NSDictionary) // works :)

let json = "[{ \"code\": \"abcde\", \"name\": \"JP Morgan\" }]"
json as! NSMutableArray // gives nil
NSMutableArray(array: json as! NSArray) // works :)
```

I would like to know why?

And I hope this helps someone solve their issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Foundation types `NSMutableArray / NSMutableDictionary` are not related to the Swift counterparts and cannot be bridged / coerced from a literally created Swift type. But that's not new in Swift 3.

Basically **do not** use `NSMutableArray / NSMutableDictionary` in Swift unless you have absolutely no choice for example interacting with a few low level CoreFoundation API. The native `Array` / `Dictionary` types used with `var` provide the same functionality (except value vs. reference semantics) and in addition the types of the containing objects.

Comment: Hmm ok thank you. I'm working on someone else's code and I know to use "native" types over ObjC ones but I didn't know it was an actual bad idea... You say thats not new to Swift3 - how come it has worked until iOS 10? (I know iOS doesn't necessarily mean Swift3 but that is when the problem started)

Comment: Actually in Swift 2 (even in the initial release Swift 1) it is not possible to cast a Swift collection type to **mutable** Foundation counterpart.

Comment: Do you think it would be safe to case anything that was headed for NSMutablexxx to the native version? Like a "replace all" type approach. Obviously fix a bug here and there but general functionality?

Comment: There is an important point to consider: You have to take care of the change form reference (Foundation types) to value (Swift types) semantics. For example if you are going to change a value in a nested array you have to get the inner array, change it then assign it back to the enclosing array. For flat types there is no difference.