# Typed Objective-C collection to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a framework written in Objective-C that I'm importing into a Swift app, using a bridging header. One of my Obj-C classes has a typed collection property:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray <MyCustomObject*> *arrayOfMyCustomObjects;
```

In the Swift app, that shows up as:

```
open var arrayOfMyCustomObjects: NSMutableArray!
```

[This page says](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-objective-c-lightweight-generics/) that a non-mutable collection would retain the type, is this the only way?

// Objective-C

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray<NSDate *> *dueDates;
```

// Swift

```
public var dueDates: [NSDate]
```

// Objective-C

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray<NSDate *> *dates;
```

// Swift

```
public var dates: NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` cannot be bridged to Swift in this way. This appears to answer your question: [iOS 10 NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray not working as before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655167/ios-10-nsmutabledictionary-and-nsmutablearray-not-working-as-before)